# c++ visitor pattern: Why should every derived visited implement Accept()?

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I've seen a couple of examples that demonstrate the visitor pattern. 
In all of them, each derived visited element implements what's usually called the Accept() method.

In a hierarchy of colors, this method might look like:

```
void Red::accept(Visitor *v)
{
    v->visit(*this);
}

void Blue::accept(Visitor *v)
{
    v->visit(*this);
}
```

When Visitor, as well as its inheritors, have the methods:

```
visit(Red red);
visit(Blue blue)
```

My question is why not implement this in the same way only in the base class (in this example: `Color`) and polymorphism will do the job, namely, the correct visit will be called since when the object is a `Red` the this's dynamic type is a `Red` so dereferencing it will yield a `Red` which in turn will cause the visit(red) to be called?

What am I missing?

Comment: if you want it in a base class then you have to use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) the get the right `this`.

Comment: In a more dynamic language you might have to name the functions `visitBlue`, and `visitRed` instead. You could do that here as well. Does that help it make sense?

Comment: The answer has already been provided, but you can find more information searching the web for "double dispatch" (I assume that you have already searched "visitor pattern" and it did not help you), which is the name of the technique used here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inheritance polymorphism (dynamic dispatch) does not apply to function arguments. In other words, overloaded function are selected on the static type of the arguments being passed. If implemented in the base class `Color`, the `v->visit(*this)` would always call `visit(Color c)`.

Comment: Clear and right to the point. What made me being confused is the fact that when I have in Base a non-virtual function and I call a virtual function from within it, the polymorphism will work and the inheritor's virtual will be called if such exists.

Comment: I would edit it to "does not apply to function arguments passed by value" (because if you pass by reference **and** you have the right virtual functions, then it will apply)...

Comment: @Massa, I believe you are mistaken. Reference or not, it's the static types of the arguments that are used to select which overloaded function is to be called. There is no double dispatch in C++, it is only simulated by this visitor pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Answer (score 1):

If the only `accept` you had was...

```
void Color::accept(Visitor* v)
{
    v->visit(*this);
}
```

`visit` would just get called with a base class. In order to call `visit` with the correct derived class you need each `Color` to implement it so they can pass a correctly typed `this`,  so the correct `visit` overload is called.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that in base class methods the `this` pointer is of type base, not of any derived classes, hence it can only access base class methods, and is passed as type `Color* this`. When passed to the visit method it would try and run `visit(Color* color)`, as polymorphic behavior only applies to methods of the class itself (not other classes).

Comment: When I have in Base a non-virtual function and I call a virtual function from within it, the polymorphism will work and the inheritor's virtual will be called if such exists, won't it?

Comment: Yes, but in that case it has access to the vtable, which handles that dynamic dispatch. It's a special case that doesn't apply across unrelated classes as used in the Visitor pattern.