# How can I reduce boilerplate with the visitor pattern in Swift?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, swift2, visitor-pattern

I am implementing the visitor pattern in Swift 2.2 for a project at work.

So that I don't have to boil down my source code and to save me some time I will use an [example of visitor pattern in swift by Oktawian Chojnacki](https://github.com/ochococo/Design-Patterns-In-Swift#-visitor).

```
protocol PlanetVisitor {
    func visit(planet: PlanetAlderaan)
    func visit(planet: PlanetCoruscant)
    func visit(planet: PlanetTatooine)
}

protocol Planet {
    func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor)
}

class PlanetAlderaan: Planet {
    func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor) { visitor.visit(self) }
}
class PlanetCoruscant: Planet {
    func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor) { visitor.visit(self) }
}
class PlanetTatooine: Planet {
    func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor) { visitor.visit(self) }
}

class NameVisitor: PlanetVisitor {
    var name = ""

    func visit(planet: PlanetAlderaan)  { name = "Alderaan" }
    func visit(planet: PlanetCoruscant) { name = "Coruscant" }
    func visit(planet: PlanetTatooine)  { name = "Tatooine" }
}
```

The problem I have been trying to solve is to reduce the boilerplate on each class that derives from `Planet`.
As you can see they all have same function duplicated `func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor) { visitor.visit(self) }`.

I have tried putting a default implementation on the `Planet` protocol and implementing it on a base class and Swift does not seem to allow it due to compile time overload resolution.

Examples:

Default Implementation on Protocol:

```
extension Planet {
    func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor) { visitor.visit(self) }
}
```

Base Class:

```
class PlanetBase: Planet {
    func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor) { visitor.visit(self) }
}

class PlanetAlderaan: PlanetBase {}
class PlanetCoruscant: PlanetBase {}
class PlanetTatooine: PlanetBase {}
```

Does anyone know of a way that the `accept` function could be made generic and applied automatically to each concrete class that derives from `Planet`? It is not a critical issue but it is a great puzzle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not possible, and this is by design.

The visitor pattern intended for the case when you have stable number of planets, but unknown yet number of visitors. So you plan for the future extensions in visitors, writing this boilerplate once. Adding more visitors then is possible with no changes to planets.

In a large project you might go with code generation.

---

**Not recommended**, your alternative is a direct switch over planets, no boilerplate code needed:

```
func foo(planet: Planet) {
    if planet is PlanetAlderaan {
        name = "Alderaan"
    }
    else if planet is PlanetCoruscant {
        name = "Coruscant"
    }
    else if planet is PlanetTatooine {
        name = "Tatooine"
    }
}
```

This is error-prone, since you can easily forget planets. Visitor pattern forces you to write code for all cases, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: You're right! For some reason I thought other languages like C++ could implement the accept method in a base class but it turns out I was wrong. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190873/c-visitor-pattern-why-should-every-derived-visited-implement-accept

Answer (score -1):

Reading @paiv answer i got idea that can you reduce boilerplate while avoiding forgetting case problem:

```
enum Planet {
    case alderaan
    case coruscant
    case tatooine

    func accept(visitor: PlanetVisitor) {
        visitor.visit(planet: self)
    }
}

protocol PlanetVisitor {
    func visit(planet: Planet)
}

class NameVisitor: PlanetVisitor {
    var name = ""

    func visit(planet: Planet) {
        switch planet {
        case .alderaan:
            name = "Alderaan"
        case .coruscant:
            name = "Coruscant"
        case .tatooine:
            name = "Tatooine"
        }
    }
}
```

If you won't use `default` in `switch` it's guaranteed that compiler wont let code compile if any case is not handled.

But I think some other boilerplate may migrate inside `Planet` type.

Comment: The Visitor pattern was invented in part to allow enum style coding in object-oriented languages. Given that Swift has great enum support, the Visitor pattern is redundant. If you look carefully at this code, any `PlanetVisitor` classes can be replaced with a function that takes the `Planet` enum directly. I don't see any benefit to the `Visitor` pattern here.